# Memory warning terminates background audio in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I'm using AVPlayer to play streaming web audio, and worked fine in iOS7 but not in iOS8.
In iOS8, audio stops playing while the app is in background, mostly when using another app that uses a lot of memory (e.g., image processing app).
I found there are lots of `didReceiveMemoryWarning`s just before the background app is terminated, so I think iOS kills the app because of lack of memory.

I tried following audio stream libraries but they all have same issue, and many apps in the AppStore also do. 
Any ideas?

- DOUAudioStreamer
- STKAudioPlayer
- AudioStreamer
- FreeStreamer
- audjustable
- RadioTunes

Comment: fix'em to not use that much ;) sorry but this is way too broad IMO - use instruments, figure out where the memory goes and THEN ask specifically about this

Comment: How exactly are you testing this?  I think I'm encountering the same issue, but it's hard to reproduce.